# Are Trade Privileges shared among islands or multiplied?

Tags: anno-1404, anno-1404-venice

The number of patricians houses (trade privileges) that I can have on an island = 60% of the number of citizens houses on that island + number of envoys worldwide/110 (improvable by certain attainments). Suppose I have 550 envoys on my oriental island. Does this mean I get 5 additional trade privileges in each of my occidental settlements or if I use 3 on one occidental island I will have only 2 remaining for the other?

If no-one answers this definitively, eventually I will (by trying), but since I currently only have one occidental settlement, I wanted to know beforehand to plan my next settlement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the additional Trade Privileges separately on each of your islands. You should see a +X beside the number of allowed patrician houses in your marketplace tool.

I just loaded one of my games to confirm:

- I have 5160 Envoys and the Envoy's Favour attainment at -20. This means I should be getting 5160/90 = +57 Trade Privileges.
- On my main island, I have 88 citizen houses, 132 patrician houses, and 88 noble houses. That's a total of 308 houses which have citizen status (or higher). 60% of that is 184, plus the 57 bonus is 241. Out of the 241 Trade Privileges, 88 are used by the noble houses, leaving 153. Indeed, it shows that I have filled 132/153 patrician houses.
- On another island, I have 124 citizens houses. 60% of that is 74, plus the 57 bonus is 131. Indeed, it shows that I have filled 0/131 patrician houses.